# Segmentation fault when trying to traverse a double linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

This is the piece of code I am using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int wordlen = 4;
typedef struct Node
{
    char* word;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
}node;
 node* head;

 node * getWord(char* x)
 {
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->word = x;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    return newNode;
 }

 void insertion(char* x)
 {
    node* temp = head;
    node* newNode = getWord(x);
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    while(temp->next != NULL) 
    temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = temp;
 }

 void print()
 {
    node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", temp->word);
        temp = temp->next;
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
 }

 void sort()
 {
    char* a = malloc((wordlen + 1)*sizeof(char));
    char* b = malloc((wordlen + 1)*sizeof(char));
    node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        a = temp->word;
        temp = temp->next;
        b = temp->word;
        if (a[0] < b[0])
        {
            //temp->word = a;
            //temp = temp->prev;
            //temp->word = b;
        }
    }
 }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    insertion("asdk");
    insertion("mapa");
    insertion("klop");
    sort();
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

The segmentation fault appears in the `sort()` function and especially in the variable `b`.
 What I have in mind is when the pointer reaches `NULL` and so the end of the list when I am trying to go back (using the prev pointer) I get the error since I don't have access to that particular block of memory. 
How exactly could I access once again the last node of my linked list once I have fully traversed through it?

Comment: You can access the last node by maintaining a tail pointer as well as a head pointer. You could even keep them in a `node` struct so you only have one variable associated with the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your loop where you don't check whether `temp->next` is NULL before dereferencing it. When it the loop gets to the end of the list, you `temp->next` is NULL. Change your loop conditions in `sort` and `insertion` to:

```
  void sort()
  {
    char* a;
    char* b;
    node* temp = head;
    while (temp && temp->next != NULL)
    {
        a = temp->word;
        temp = temp->next;
        b = temp->word;
        if (a[0] < b[0])
        {
            temp->word = a;
            temp = temp->prev;
            temp->word = b;
        }
    }
  }

 void insertion(char* x)
 {
    node* temp = head;
    node* newNode = getWord(x);
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    while(temp && temp->next != NULL) 
    temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = temp;
 }
```

Besides, you don't need to allocate memory for `a` and `b`. You just use temporary pointer variables to swap.

Comment: with this solution arent i gonna lose the pointer to the last node?

Comment: @Korpel No. The loop loops one node "ahead". You read two nodes in each iteration. One is current node and another is the next node. If you have only one node, the loop won't run. If you have 2 nodes, it'll run once. If you have 3 nodes, it'll run twice and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You have a big memory leak in `sort`:

```
char* a = malloc((wordlen + 1)*sizeof(char));
char* b = malloc((wordlen + 1)*sizeof(char));
...
    a = temp->word;        // This leaks a
    ...
    b = temp->word;        // This leaks b
```

You can't assign strings in C, you need to copy them with `strcpy`.

You also should test each `malloc` return for `NULL`. And please don't multiply by `sizeof(char)`, it is 1 by definition in the C Standard. If you want to multiply, use `sizeof(*a)` which is always correct, no matter what type `a` points to.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are many problems with your program (specially in sort function).

**First**, consider you are at last element in below while loop.

```
while (temp != NULL)
    {
        a = temp->word;
        temp = temp->next;
        b = temp->word;
        if (a[0] < b[0])
        {
            //temp->word = a;
            //temp = temp->prev;
            //temp->word = b;
        }
    }
 }
```

This line `temp = temp->next;` will lead temp to NULL when loop is executing for the last node. Deferencing temp after that is itself problemactic.

**Solution:** check temp->next !=NULl instead of temp==NULL.

**Second**, you are allocating memory but not freeing it.

```
char* a = malloc((wordlen + 1)*sizeof(char));
char* b = malloc((wordlen + 1)*sizeof(char));
```

**Solution:** Free this memory.

**Third**, the way you copy strings is not supported in C.

```
 a = temp->word;
 b = temp->word;
```

**Solution:** Use strcpy()